# sobrescribir metodo de clase y acceder a la original al mismo tiempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, herencia, diseño-de-clases

Me gustaría saber si es posible al heredar de una clase sobrescribir un método  y al mismo tiempo poder acceder al método original.

La idea es poder realizar acciones extra que solo se dan en una clase pero mantener el nombre del método.

La clase Puerta hace las acciones mas sencillas mientras que la clase PuertaConCerradura realiza acciones extra.

Pongo un ejemplo sencillo:

## edito: Reflejo el resultado de aplicar la respuesta

```
class Puerta:
    def __init__(self, estado):
        self.estado = estado

    def abre(self):
        self.estado = 'abierta'
        return 'Giras el pomo y abres la puerta'

    def cierra(self):
        self.estado = 'cerrada'
        return 'cierras la puerta'
    def di_estado(self):
        estado = 'La puerta esta %s' % self.estado
        print(estado)
        return estado

class PuertaConCerradura(Puerta):
    def __init__(self, estado, bloqueada):
        Puerta.__init__(self, estado)
        self.bloqueada = bloqueada

    def abre(self):
        accion = ''
        if self.bloqueada:
            accion = '%s' % ('Metes la llave y desbloqueas la puerta\n')
            self.bloqueada = False
        accion = '%s%s' % (accion, super().abre())
        print(accion)
        return accion

    def cierra(self, bloquear=False):
        accion = super().cierra()
        if bloquear:
            self.bloqueada = True
            accion = '%s\n%s' % (accion, 'Metes la llave y bloqueas la puerta')
        print(accion)
        return accion

    def di_estado(self):
        estado = super().di_estado()
        if self.bloqueada:
            accion = 'Además la puerta esta cerrada con llave'
            estado = '%s\n%s' % (estado, accion)
            print(accion)
        return estado
```

Comment: En realidad ya te has respondido a ti mismo ¿no? El método `abre()` de la clase `PuertaConCerradura` sobreescribe al `abre()` de la clase `Puerta`, pero aún puede llamarlo, como tú mismo haces, mediante `Puerta.abre()`. Esto que has hecho es perfectamente válido si sabes que `PuertaConCerradura` hereda de `Puerta`. Si no lo sabes (o quieres que el código llame al `abre()` de su clase base, _sea esta cual sea_) puedes hacer uso de `super()` como te han respondido. Si tienes herencia múltiple la cosa puede complicarse bastante más, pues tendrás varias clases base ¿a cuál querrías llamar?

Comment: Se me olvidó señalar que, eso sí, el método `abre()`, tanto de la clase `Puerta` como de `PuertaConCerradura` espera un primer parámetro que sea el objeto sobre el que actuar (`self`). Cuando usas `objeto.metodo()` para invocar, Python automáticamente añade ese primer parámetro, y convierte esa llamada en `Clase.metodo(objeto)`, pero cuando usas `Clase.metodo()` debes añadirlo tú a mano. Por tanto lo que escribiste como `Puerta.abre()` debe ser `Puerta.abre(self)`. Usando `super()`  no tienes este problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si.

Puedes acceder a la función de la clase de la que heredas a través de la función [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super).

Si lo que quieres es poder sobreescribirla y aun así llamar a la del padre no vas a poder llamarla igual, porque 1. En Python no existe sobrecarga, 2. Has sobreescrito el método!

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```py
class A():
    def pepe():
        print("Estoy en A")

class B():
    def pepe():
        print("Estoy en B")
        super(B, self).pepe()

b = B()
b.pepe()  #Esto imprime "Estoy en B" y después "Estoy en A"
```

En caso de que la función reciba parámetros, pásaselos normalmente

Comment: En python3 puedes incluso omitir los parámetros de `self()`, y poner simplemente `self().pepe()` (los parámetros por defecto son la clase desde la que es invocado, `B`, y el objeto desde el que es invocado, `self`)

Comment: muchas gracias, conocía super() pero nunca lo había usado, he modificado el código para reflejar el resultado final

Comment: abulafia no entiendo a que te refieres, he probado cambiar super() por self() y no ha funcionado

Comment: Parece que @abulafia se refería a `super()` en lugar de `self()`. `self` es el nombre que se le da a la instancia _por convenio_.